# Расчет скидок для продажи и возврата МойСклад

Tags: moysklad-pos-api, moysklad-phone-api

пытаемся через Api запросить расчет скидки при продаже по документации https://online.moysklad.ru/api/posap/1.0/doc/index.html
и столкнулись с проблемой, перерасчета по скидкам вообще не происходит

На товар должна была преминиться 10% скидка

Запрос на https://online.moysklad.ru/api/posap/1.0/rpc/retaildemand/recalc

```
{
    "agent":{
        "meta":{
            "href":"###",
            "metadataHref":"###",
            "type":"counterparty",
            "mediaType":"application/json",
            "uuidHref":"###"
        }
    }, 
    "transactionType":"EARNING",
    "positions":[{
        "assortment":{
            "meta":{
                "href":"###",
                "metadataHref":"###",
                "type":"product",
                "mediaType":"application/json",
                "uuidHref":"###"
            }
        },
        "quantity":"1",
        "price":550
    }]
}
```

Ответ от Api

```
{
    "positions":[{
        "assortment":{
            "meta":{
                "href":"###",
                "mediaType":"application/json",
                "type":"product",
                "id":"###",
                "idType":"native"
            },
            "name":"###",
            "code":"###",
            "barcodes":["2000000109848"],
            "uom":"шт",
            "paymentItemType":"GOOD",
            "image":{
                "href":"###",
                "miniature":"###",
                "tiny":"###"
            },
            "soldByWeight":false,
            "tobacco":false,
            "trackingType":"NOT_TRACKED",
            "isSerialTrackable":false
        },
        "quantity":1.0,
        "price":550,
        "discountedPrice":550
    }],
    "agentBonusBalance":0,
    "bonusValueToEarn":0,
    "bonusValueToSpend":0,
    "chequeSumWithoutDiscount":550,
    "paidByDiscountWithoutBonus":0,
    "paidWithBonusPoints":0,
    "valueToPay":550
}
```

Comment: Скидки применяются автоматически, через POS можно только запросить скидки на просмотр

Comment: В api есть функций [Расчет скидок для продажи и возврата](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/posap/1.0/doc/index.html#pos_doc-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0) делал все по документации и именно она не возвращаяет скидки

Comment: Можете дополнить описание запросами и ответами сервиса, чтобы можно было более детально разобраться в проблеме

Comment: Добавил описание запроса и ответ от API

Comment: Установлена ли скидка на это товар в системе?

Comment: Проверяли на реальной продаже, на скидка установлена